# How to make watson assistant search for multiple watson discovery collections?

Tags: webhooks, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery, ibm-cloud-functions

I am Using  IBM cloud functions to link assistant and discovery. However, there is only 1 webhook url slot available, which means I can only use 1 function, which in turn can only have 1 collection Id.
I need a way through with assistant can look into multiple discovery collections.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is within the Watson Discovery API an api call that will search multiple collections similar to the single collection api call. This particular call will take multiple collection id's and search these. The api call is similar to the single collection api call, and thus is a simple change to the cloud function. I have used it myself. Your only consideration now is if the different collections return different JSON payloads, and thus how you manage these. In my case I created a default standard JSON payload that then gets returned to Watson Assistant, and merge the different results into this standard payload.